# How to use MockRestServiceServer with RestClient in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, mocking

I am updating some services from RestTemplate to RestClient. But I can't get `MockRestServiceServer` to work with RestClient.

The equivalent that I want to replace

```java
    @Autowired
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() {
        server = MockRestServiceServer.createServer(restTemplate);
    }
```

See full code sample at

https://github.com/MV-GH/repro-cat-fact-restclient-mockrestserviceserver/tree/rest-template